# String to int conversion error

Tags: java, parsing, floating-point, complex-numbers

My string contains floating numbers with positive and negative sign and character.  Basically complex numbers. I have to separate them first from string then further as real and imaginary, keeping in mind that sign should remain along the number.

Currently, I am using Split to get them separated as sub strings but further in separating real and imaginary I get error reading negative sign. Need help.

this is my string "-0.6026630828112783-0.6026630828112783 i+0.012343244232-0.90293888321i..."

I use String.split("[\Q+-\Ei]"); and i get -0.6026630828112783-0.6026630828112783i (1st number). i further want to separate real and imaginary along with sign

Comment: Could you please share what you've attempted so far?

Comment: this is my string    "-0.6026630828112783-0.6026630828112783 i+0.012343244232-0.90293888321i..."

Comment: I use String.split("[\\Q+-\\Ei]"); and i get -0.6026630828112783-0.6026630828112783i (1st number). i further want to separate real and imaginary along with sign

Comment: Please edit your question to add your comments as a part of the question. Those who are going to answer your question will need all the details, because they cannot read the files on your computer :)

Comment: Can't convert any decimal to int. converting string to int should always be done with caution and proper pre-condition checks and error handling.

Answer (score 2):

Use Below Code to Convert `String` to `int` :)

```
Integer.parseInt("" +  Math.round(Float.parseFloat("-12.233")))
```

For Split numbers, First Add Separator Char before `+` and `-`. Like `,`.
Then Split by Separator Char.

Comment: this is just rounding the number. Not the solution required

Comment: When I wrote comment, Question had less information. Now I complete too ;) @BilalAhmed